# How can I resolve problem with tag_add in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tags

I want to mark the specific day which I insert in a string. I do this with a `tag_add`. I don't know why but codes doesn't work right. Can you check where could be a problem.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Text #renames to ttk
import tkinter.messagebox
import calendar

text = Text()
text.pack()
text.tag_configure("dan", background='light grey', foreground='blue')

# Display calendar
month = calendar.month(2020, 2, 2, 1)
text.insert('1.0', month)

# Get a day, index of a day in the string month, and then color the day
datum = "2020 02 11"
d = datum.split()
y = int(d[0])
m = int(d[1]) 
day = d[2]
day = month.find(day)
text.tag_add('dan', f"{day}.18", f"{day}.20") # ?? Maybe problem here??

text.mainloop()
```

All the best,
Domen

Comment: Question. what do you mean by `#renames to ttk` ? You are importing Text twice here. That has nothing to do with ttk. That said you are missing `Tk()`. They way you are using `mainloop()` here is incorrect.

Comment: What does "doesn't work right" mean? What is the code you posted doing, and how is it different from what you expect? What have you done to debug this? Have you looked at what `f"{day}.18"` is, and verified that it is the correct value?

Answer (score 2):

Your `month.find()` returns 83. This is the string start index of 11 so what you have told your tag to do is start on row 83 column 18 of the textbox. What you probably want to do is split `month` into a list of rows. This can be done with `splitlines()`. Then we write in a for loop to check what row contains the day and from there we do `row.find()` to get the proper column index.

Give this a shot and let me know if you have any questions:

```
import tkinter as tk
import calendar

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text()
text.pack()
text.tag_configure("dan", background='light grey', foreground='blue')
month = calendar.month(2020, 2, 2, 1)
text.insert('1.0', month)
datum = "2020 02 11"
d = datum.split()
y = int(d[0])
m = int(d[1])
day = d[2]

for ndex, row in enumerate(month.splitlines()):
    if day in row:
        col_index = row.find(day)
        text.tag_add('dan', '{}.{}'.format(ndex+1, col_index), '{}.{}'.format(ndex+1, col_index + len(day)))
        break

text.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, The cod is working good. I just notice one problem... if I want to tag a day 20 (year 2020), the program will mark first 20 in year 2020. Is it possible to start searching not in the first row, but in the second or third?